# Numba: double free or corruption (!prev) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to speed up the following function using numba.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def find_reg_numba(states):
    reg = []    
    states_sum = np.sum(states, axis=1)
    for i in prange(states.shape[0]):
        if states_sum[i] > 0 and states_sum[i] < 5:
            reg.append(states[i])
    return reg
```

The `states` is generated using the following function

```
def generate_states(size):
    # size is a natural number
    states = np.array(list(map(list, itertools.product([0., 1.], repeat = size))))
    return states
```

When I try to use the `find_reg` function, I get the following error trace.

```
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My numba version is `0.48.0`.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You have `reg = []; reg = []`.  Did you want: `reg = []; reg_size = []`.  Also `find_reg_numba` doesn't return anything.  Do you want: `return reg, reg_size`?

Comment: I've edited my code, I only want `reg` since `reg_size` can be calculated later.

Comment: Strangely most runs of your code are okay, but occasionally I get:the error `double free or corruption (!prev)
repl process died unexpectedly: signal: aborted (core dumped)`.  This doesn't happen in the non-Numba version (i.e. not using the decorator).

Comment: I'm getting `double free or corruption (!prev)Segmentation fault (core dumped)` for all runs. My numba version is `0.48.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your code produces an error.  Related error posts are:

- [numpy double free or corruption (!prev) segmentation fault](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10089)
- [Error in `python': double free or corruption (!prev)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6968)
- [Python double free error for huge datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906962/python-double-free-error-for-huge-datasets)

However, these proved unhelpful.

Here's an alternative Numba version of find_reg_numba which:

1. Runs without errors
2. Produces the same result as the original code without Numba (i.e. original produces errors only with Numba).

**Code Refactoring**

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import itertools

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def find_reg_numba(states):
    states_sum = np.sum(states, axis=1)

    # Find indexes satisfying condition using np.where as described https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-where-in-python/
    indexes = np.where((states_sum > 0) & (states_sum < 5))
    return states[indexes]

def generate_states(size):
    # size is a natural number
    states = np.array(list(map(list, itertools.product([0., 1.], repeat = size))))
    return states
```

**Tests**

```
for size in range(10):
  s = generate_states(size)
  r  = find_reg_numba(s)
  print(f'Size: {size}\n Result: \n{r}')
```

**Results**

```
 Size: 0
 Result:
[]
Size: 1
 Result:
[[1.]]
Size: 2
 Result:
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 1.]]
Size: 3
 Result:
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
Size: 4
 Result:
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]]
Size: 5
 Result:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]
Size: 6
 Result:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]]
Size: 7
 Result:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
Size: 8
 Result:
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
Size: 9
 Result:
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is that `list.append` method is not thread safe. If you comment out that line, you wont get the error
2. Intuitively it makes sense that append is not thread safe. Think about what happens when 2 threads try to append to the end of the same list. They will both be writing to the same memory address
3. Admittedly Numba documentation can be sparse. But it does mention that when using prange, it's up to the user to ensure there are no "cross iteration dependencies" [link](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#explicit-parallel-loops)
4. You can fix the error by pre-initialising the list and then setting the values via indexing.

For example

```
  import numpy as np
  from numba import jit, prange
  
  @jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
  def find_reg_numba(states):
      # initialize reg to be a populated with dummy values of the same type that we will eventually populate it with
      reg = [np.empty(1).astype(states[0].dtype) for i in range(states.shape[0])]    
      states_sum = np.sum(states, axis=1)
      for i in prange(states.shape[0]):
          if states_sum[i] > 0 and states_sum[i] < 5:
              reg[i] = states[i]
      return reg
```